# pandas to_datetime throwing a value error for incorrect date format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe I am trying to clean. its not dates formatted in a string so Im converting it to datetime using:

`df['datecreated']= pd.to_datetime(df['datecreated'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`

getting an error:

`ValueError: time data "2021-09-16 16:32:11.643333" doesn't match format specified`

however when I test it separately, it runs:

[image]

Why am I getting the ValueError ?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2084         try:
-> 2085             values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
   2086             # If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-63141dd04215> in <module>
----> 1 df['datecreated']= pd.to_datetime(df['datecreated'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
      2 df

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    803             result = arg.map(cache_array)
    804         else:
--> 805             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
    806             result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    807     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    470             errors=errors,
    471             require_iso8601=require_iso8601,
--> 472             allow_object=True,
    473         )
    474 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2088             return values.view("i8"), tz_parsed
   2089         except (ValueError, TypeError):
-> 2090             raise e
   2091 
   2092     if tz_parsed is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2079             dayfirst=dayfirst,
   2080             yearfirst=yearfirst,
-> 2081             require_iso8601=require_iso8601,
   2082         )
   2083     except ValueError as e:

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

ValueError: time data "2021-09-16 16:32:11.643333" doesn't match format specified
```

**Update**

I tried adding: errors='coerce'

but the datecreated column is now NaT. that doesnt help me

Comment: Hey, Dhruv. Try pass pd.to_datetime() without the format parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date strings have extra double quotes at both ends, causing the format mismatch error, you are better to remove the double quotes before invoking `pd.to_datetime`.  In this way, if you have other elements without the double quotes, the codes still work for all entries with and without double quotes:

You can use [`.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) to remove the double quotes at both ends:

```
df['datecreated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datecreated'].str.strip('"'), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

as the error suggests:

`ValueError: time data "2021-09-16 16:32:11.643333" doesn't match format specified`

the format needed the quotation marks as well.

`df['datecreated']= pd.to_datetime(df['datecreated'], format='"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"')`